# Error: Android SDK not found with ionic run android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, genymotion

I have try to debug fro a few days. I want to run ionic code with Genymotion as emulator. I am using **windows 10**. My C drive is run out of space and I installed everything in **D drive**.

However, when I run ionic run android, I get the `Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.`

I have the SDK directories as below:
[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2][![enter image description here][3]][3]

I also set the Environment Variables with ANDROID_HOME and its path
[![enter image description here][4]][4][![enter image description here][5]][5]

Besides, I also try numerous way to set the path as below, but all still fail with same error.

D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\tools and D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\platform-tools

D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\platform-tools only

ANDOIRD_HOME set to D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\

remove ANDROID_HOME and set path D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\platform-tools and D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397\tools

The adb is working and able to detect the device in genymotion
[![enter image description here][6]][6]

I think I have try almost everything but still see the error. Please advice how to make it work.
If I run only `ionic serve`, there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link:

http://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-set-path-environmental-variable-for-sdk-in-windows/

Or open command prompt and exec:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Comment: I try before, and since the link is not win10, I set ANDOID_HOME in user variables and also environment variables, both see same error.

Comment: when open command prompt, it point to users/myname directory, shall I use the set ANDROID_HOME there? Please noted that I do not have `android-sdk` folder but only `D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397`

Comment: Change answer. Try again.

Comment: I did as you said http://i.imgur.com/Ti8RW4t.png. but still have the same error. How to confirm is a SDK really in the directory?

Comment: I try `sdkmananger --list` at cmd, and it return `'sdkmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: cd D:\sdk-tools-windows-3859397 and exec dir and show me.

Comment: Exec set in cmd check ANDROID_HOME in list. Please rest your pc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148278/discussion-between-bkcollection-and-ahmad-aghazadeh).